# Python script works interactively but not when called from shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

This simple script works fine when I load it in an iPython interactive shell.  All the function calls work as expected.  Variables are correct.  The for loop at the end works fine.  When I call it from the command line with `python3 <script>` or `python <script>` (both are v3.7.3), I get an error from the json module: `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

More context:  The iPython session is loaded in the same environment in which the script is being called.  Python version is the same.  Environment variable is the same.  IPython is v7.8.
Code:

```
import json
import os
import requests as re

spark_apps_url = os.environ.get('SPARK_URL')

def get_app_ids():
    # returns list of appIDs to be used for generating endpoints
    r = re.get(spark_apps_url)
    appsJSON = r.json()
    appIDs = [app['id'] for app in appsJSON]
    return appIDs

def get_jobs(appID: str):
    # returns list of job dict from app by appID
    jobs = re.get(f"{spark_apps_url}/{appID}/jobs").json()
    return jobs

for appID in get_app_ids():
    print(get_jobs(appID))
```

Comment: cn you print the variable before the JSON conversion kicks in. Both in your ipython and when you run it.

Comment: Is `$SPARK_URL` set when you run as a script?

Comment: @snakecharmerb yep

Comment: @leoOrion which variable?  `appID`?  Both methods print that, confirmed.   The printed varaible is a string of the app's ID.

Comment: What is being converted from json ? You are getting a json decode error. Which means tehre is something wrong in what it is converting. Can you check what that is in both cases

Comment: @leoOrion interesting.  In iPython, the object calling `json()` is a response object with code 200.  When running the script, it's a 404.  I've confirmed that the shell session I'm running the script from has access to the url.  When I `curl $SPARK_URL`, I get the expected data.

Comment: Well you found your root cause. Since it's an API you need to now check why the 404

Comment: @leoOrion well sort of, right?  It's not necessarily an issue with accessing the API, in general, as the interactive version gets a 200 response and the expected data.  Why would my interactive shell get a 200 and the script run from command line return 404?  All other factors are controlled (are equal) as far as I can tell.  Any suggestions on what to check for?

Comment: You could check the other end of the API to see if a request is reaching it. See if  there is a difference in the request params there for both cases.

Comment: @leoOrion Only different in requests from perspective the API was trace ID for the request.  There is something different about the script running from CL and running in iPython.

Comment: Try a simple curl with the same endpoint. Do u still get a response ?     Another thing I can think of is the env variable u r setting. Is that being correctly rendered when u r calling ur python script